# conversion from 'char**' to 'QChar' is ambiguous

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qstring, qt5.4

I am working on a very simple and quick program in qt to convert an entire file to a single line string and prints it out. It is run through the command line. I have one problem. When compiling the program Qt Creator gives me this error `conversion from 'char**' to 'QChar' is ambiguous        main.cpp        12`

Here's my code:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString b (argv);
    QFile sFile(b);
    QTextStream in(&sFile);
    QString text = in.readAll();
    sFile.close();

    QStringList doc;
    doc<< text;
    QString f = doc.join(" ");
    QString final = f;
    qDebug()<<final;

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Read that the compiler error again. You are passing (char **) to QString constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`argv` is a vector of `char*` (c strings). choose the string you are interested in:

`QString b(argv[1]);`